# How to fix images not moving when page moves

Tags: html, css

I am working on a personal portfolio website and having trouble getting an image to move when the screen does.

Sorry if I explain any of this bad but what I have is in imaged centered and when the page gets smaller I want the image to resize proportionally. (I thought flexbox did this but I could not find an answer there)

```
<div class="photopage">
    <img src="images/titlepage.png">
</div>
```

Is this the right Html? or should I just have an image.

At the moment my CSS just sets the img over 10vw. I realize that is not the way to go if I want everything to stay centered and proportioned when the screen moves.

Comment: Better you can use bootstrap for the responsive designs

Answer (score 2):

You just want to give the image some sort of relative width, so that it will scale relative to the width of the parent, screen width (`vw`), etc.

The easiest way to get the image to scale with it's container is just to use `max-width: 100%;`. As the parent resizes, the image will resize inside of it relative to the parent width.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photopage">
  <img src="http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Our-Entire-Galaxy-Might-Be-One-Mammoth-Wormhole-Brainiacs-Say-470824-2.jpg">
</div>
```

Here's an example of how to scale the image with the viewport width.

```css
img {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="photopage">
  <img src="http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Our-Entire-Galaxy-Might-Be-One-Mammoth-Wormhole-Brainiacs-Say-470824-2.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you wanted to do?

[HTML]

```
<p>
   this is a paragraph
</p>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p>
this is a paragraph
</p>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p>
this is a paragraph
</p>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p>
this is a paragraph
</p>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

[CSS]

```
html {
background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/20/15/12/ring-nebula-1995076_960_720.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hass/p3dk2t6k/